# Change position button add-link in extension MultiModelForm

Tags: css, tags, position

I'm using the extension `MultiModelForm` (http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/multimodelform/)

How do I change the position of the button `Add Row`? I want to appear under my table. The button appears above my table, but when the user enters must return many rows up to press the button to add more rows and that's not very practical ... I try to modify the file `MultiModelForm.php` but could not change the location of the button :( ....thanks for everything

Answer (score 0):

http://api.jquery.com/clone/

$('#the_button').clone().appendTo('#another_place');
or
$('#the_button').clone().prependTo('#another_place');